# update statement conflicted with foreign key constraint. How do I fix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
UPDATE TRANS
SET DateSold = '11/18/2010', SalesPrice = 475.00,
CustomerID = 1056 
WHERE TransactionID = 229;
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem in your business logic for this example : if you have a foreign key error, you are trying to use a customer which doesn't exist (unless you have defined a foreign key relationship on DateSold or SalesPrice, which would be unusual).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` option while defining or creating your FOREIGN KEY constraint. That way, your new updates will get reflected to relationships.